# Request-URI Too Long using webservices

Tags: apache, web-services, codeigniter, url

I am having one webservice to sync order data from Ipad offline app to live server. Sometimes webservice is working fine but sometimes it is not. 
So when I am trying to call that webservice to resolve the issue through url using Postman, I am getting below error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>414 Request-URI Too Long</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Request-URI Too Long</h1>
        <p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.
            <br />
        </p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at ip-172-31-31-143.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please provide me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a shorter URI. It's telling you that the URI is too long. What is the URI? If you're passing a bunch of data via query string parameters, maybe you can convert to POST data.

Answer (score 0):

The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) contains a URL that is simply too large i.e. too many bytes.

Typically Web servers set fairly generous limits on length for genuine URLs e.g. up to 2048 or 4096 characters. If your URL is particularly long, you can usually try shorter variations to see roughly where the limit is. If your long URL is indeed valid, then the Web server may need to be reconfigured to allow your URLs through. Understand that Web servers have to set some reasonable limit here, because they have to deal with badly programmed clients trying to give them huge garbage URLs.

**Fixing 414 errors - general**

This error seldom occurs in most Web traffic, particularly when the client system is a Web browser. The URLs in this case are typically standard hyperlinks found on Web pages. These links tend to be too large if they are simply wrong i.e. the Web page containing the link has been badly coded.

If your client system is not a Web browser, the problem can only be resolved by examining what the client is trying to do then discussing with your ISP why the Web server rejects the size of the URL sent by the client system.